# need help for swt.widgets.DateTime in eclipse-rcp for time format while accessing through the database

Tags: sql-server, eclipse-rcp

i have use the **DateTime**  control that show only **time** in my design view in PM, Am format  and user select only time from that one. i am using a column name ***timeFrom*** which i delcare a **dataType time(7)** in my mssql database. i can save it easily into the database as

```
objBookingModel.settimeFrom(timeFrom.getHours() + ":"
                + timeFrom.getMinutes() + ":" + timeFrom.getSeconds());
```

Suppose i enter **10:54:44 pm** in the design view it is stored in the database as **22:54:44**.  now please Help how to format **22:54:44** as **10:54:44 PM** when i want to show back it in design view from the databse. should i have to use `timefrom.setTime( );?`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Time time; // you have this from your Database query
DateTime dateTime; // you have this already or will create a new one

Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(time.getTime());
dateTime.setTime(calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR), calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE),calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND));
```

This one was the answer i worked with might be helpful to thers.................